# Does exist some formal name for 3 dimentional "matrix"?

Tags: matrices

What I am looking for is a name in mathematics or even a part of mathematics which has some interpretation for an cubic form of matrices like $2 \times 2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3 \times 3$ or any like that?

For example $2 \times 2 \times 2$ matrix could look like composition of:
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
from one site, but it is also represents by composition of:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
like a projection of that cube from other side.

Comment: Tensor is the name.